# How to lower SharePoint 2013 memory usage?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, performance

Can SharePoint be turned off?

Idea is this:

SharePoint 2013 uses lot of memory and customer needs this memory every night. Customer is doing some memory intensive work every night.
Is there any way force SharePoint to use less memory?

What I think, that I can create PowerShell scripts and turn off example search, etc... But I don't know if this is good idea. Has anyone done a similar task?

Any ideas/tips/trick how to lower SharePoint memory usage only night time?

Comment: you can turn off some services, or add some servers to your farm for services. (without increasing memory but redistributing the hardware)

Comment: what is customer doing? working in sharepoint or doing non sharepoint activities which required more memory?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't post comment. I also faced similar issue. I followed below mentioned steps:

1. Take daily backup of logs and clear logs on daily basis.
2. Schedule all daily timer jobs to take place in particular time range in day to free resources in night.
3. Stop less used services like Central Admin service.
4. If you are not using emails then stop SMTP service, Inbound/Outbound email services.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do that has a practical impact is to make sure you use a minimal amount of Application Pools. All Service Applications into a single pool and all Web Applications into a single pool (Central Administration excluded, of course). .NET carves out a private address space for each pool. I wrote about this more in-depth here: [The Expense of Application Pools](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/08/expense-application-pools/). Other than that, disabling Search will yield a significant amount of memory back to the system.

Ultimately, I'd suggest another server for these "intensive" tasks. SharePoint itself is an intensive task, after all.